# Using a variable in a view creation script in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, select, sql-view

I now have an intermediate view in SQL Server, and a final view, as follows:

Intermediate view:

```
SELECT
    ....
    ElapsedDays = DATEDIFF(d, ri.DateReceived, GETDATE()),
    .....
FROM 
    RegionalInventory AS ri
```

Final view:

```
SELECT
    ....
    PenaltyBucket = COALESCE(CASE WHEN inv.ElapsedDays <= 30 THEN 'Not Late' END,
                             CASE WHEN inv.ElapsedDays > 30 THEN 'Late' END)
    ....
FROM 
    Inventory AS inv
```

I am wondering if there's a way for me to combine both views into one, but I am not sure how to declare a variable to hold the value of `ElapsedDays`, and then use it to set the value for the `ElapsedDays` column and to do the logical test, to both create the `PenaltyBucket` column and fill it with the right value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that you really have only one table (called `RegionalInventory`, this is a convenient place for a lateral join:

```
SELECT . . ., v.ElapsedDays,
       (CASE WHEN v.ElapsedDays <= 30 THEN 'Not Late'
             WHEN v.ElapsedDays > 30 THEN 'Late'
        END) as PenaltyBucket
FROM RegionalInventory ri CROSS APPLY
     (VALUES (DATEDIFF(day, ri.DateReceived, GETDATE()))
     ) v(ElapsedDays);
```

Note:

- There is no need to use `COALESCE()` with two `CASE` expressions.  One `CASE` can handle multiple conditions.
- Spell out `day` when using `DATEDIFF()`.  That is just a good habit (consider:  does `m` mean minutes or months?)

Comment: I actually have more than two CASE expressions, but listed only two here for brevity and I am only dealing with one table. I till test this out

Comment: @coyotepoint . . . The values clause can define multiple columns:  `(values ( . . . , . . . , . . .)) v(a, b, c)`.

Answer (score 3):

You can just repeat the expression in the `SELECT` clause:

```
SELECT
    ...,
    DATEDIFF(d, ri.DateReceived, GETDATE()) AS ElapsedDays,
    CASE 
        WHEN DATEDIFF(d, ri.DateReceived, GETDATE()) <= 30 then 'Not Late'
        ELSE 'Late' 
    END AS PenaltyBucket 
    ...
FROM RegionalInventory as ri
```

Alternatively, you can use a subquery:

```
SELECT
    t.*,
    CASE 
        WHEN ElapsedDays  <= 30 then 'Not Late'
        ELSE 'Late' 
    END AS PenaltyBucket 
FROM (
    SELECT
        ...,
        DATEDIFF(d, ri.DateReceived, GETDATE()) AS ElapsedDays,
        ...
    FROM RegionalInventory as ri
) t
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define inner view as a CTE and then refer it again.

> CREATE VIEW [ schema_name . ] view_name [  ( column_name [ ,...n ] ) ]
> AS <select_statement>    [;]      <select_statement> ::=
> [ WITH <common_table_expression> [ ,...n ] ]
> SELECT <select_criteria>

Below is demo code for your reference.

```sql
create view vw_test
as 
WITH cte_1 as
(
select 1 as a
)
SELECT t.testname
from (values (1,'test1'),(2,'test2')) as t(a,testname)
join cte_1 as c
on c.a = t.a

select * from vw_test
```

What you can do is. Sample code for your reference.

```sql
CREATE VIEW outerView
AS
WITH cte_innerview
as
(
SELECT
    ....
    ElapsedDays = DATEDIFF(d, ri.DateReceived, GETDATE()),
    .....
FROM 
    RegionalInventory AS ri
)
SELECT
    ....
    PenaltyBucket = COALESCE(CASE WHEN inv.ElapsedDays <= 30 THEN 'Not Late' END,
                             CASE WHEN inv.ElapsedDays > 30 THEN 'Late' END)
    ....
FROM 
    Inventory AS inv
INNER JOIN cte_innerview as c
on c.InventoryId = inv.InventoryId
```